# I can access site with host name IIS in local but not from other machines

Tags: iis, web-hosting, iis-8

Please check the way I configure.

- Type : https
- IP Address : All Unassigned
- Port : 443
- Host name : testing.mysite.com

Give ssl certificate that matches url and added DNS entry in hosts file.

And finally, my question is that is there any way to access the site from other machines. I mean access the site as `https://<IP>:<port>/directory/filename`

I can ping testing.mysite.com locally (pings with 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

If you only created the DNS entry in the HOSTS file on the server itself, then other machines won't be able to browse to that site based on the name.  You need a DNS A record in DNS that points your domain name to the appropriate IP address so that other systems can resolve the name.

Comment: 'You need a DNS A record in DNS that points your domain name to the appropriate IP address'

Can you test as you said. In my case it was not working. I tried that before asking this question.

Comment: testing.mysite.com resolves fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hosts file entry remotely on a client and see if you things work.  Once that is all set, you'll just need the dns A record as mentioned in the previous post.  This is something I do all the time to make sure the setup is working both locally as well as remotely.